# Getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with ipython2 notebook

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

With a recent upgrade I am now running into a serious problem with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when starting a python2.7 instance of the notebook with `$ ipython2 notebook`.

The error seems to originate through `tornado` which uses `ayncio` and in that library there is python3.4 syntax.

I can start with `$ ipython3 notebook`, but the application I am doing is using `mayavi` which I believe is still for python2 only.

The nasty error message is:

```
$ ipython2 notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython2", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tornado import gen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1236, in <module>
    import tornado.platform.asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 33, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import selectors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asyncio/selectors.py", line 39
    "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What would help in my sitation? Downgrading tornado? Is there something wrong in my setup. Why is it at all possible to install asyncio under python2.7?

Comment: Could you please open a bug report on the Tornado project? If this is a common enough problem, a patch to Tornado may be able support both Python 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: Tornado supports both Python 2.7 and 3.x. AFAIU (see my answer below). My understanding now is that it was a problem with requirements either specific to my system (i.e. my error) or somewhere else. Reading https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/setup.py I do not see how asyncio/trollius are included. I am wondering whether this is a tornado issue at all.

Answer (score 8):

Downgrading tornado works:

```
$ sudo pip install tornado==4.1
$ ipython2 notebook
[I 17:22:31.800 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/fnielsen/fnielsen/ipynb
...
```

Comment: Note that this does not solve the underlying problem. Better it seems to exchange `asyncio` with `trollius`: `$ sudo pip2 uninstall asyncio` followed by `$ sudo pip2 install trollius`. `tornado` (4.1 and 4.3) and `notebook` works after this.